# Merge Series and DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to merge a series with an index that is the same as a dataframe columns.

I have tried pd.concat, but that doesnt work.

I want

```
samp_series = pd.Series([1,2], index=['a', 'b'])
samp_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4], 'b': [5,6]})


want = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 5, 6]})
```

I have tried:

```
pd.concat([samp_series, samp_df], axis=0)
```

I would like the "want" dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your `Series` to a `pandas DataFrame` and after that [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the index to columns. Finally you can concat these two dataframes:

```
want = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(samp_series).T, samp_df], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print(want)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  5
2  4  6
```

Answer (score 1):

You usually add a row from a `Series` (or a `list` or a `dict` or …) into an existing `DataFrame` using [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#appending-rows-to-a-dataframe). So

```
samp_df.append(samp_series, ignore_index=True)
```

should work like a charm.

However, you seem to be willing to go the other way around and prepend the `Series` to the `DataFrame`. In such case, you will have to adapt your data a bit and transform your `Series` to a `DataFrame` so other functions will work properly:

```
samp_almost_series = pd.DataFrame(samp_series).T
wanted = samp_almost_series.append(samp_df)
```

---

A last resort solution if you do not want to use an intermediate `DataFrame` would be to "insert" your `Series` at a `loc`action before any existing index in `samp_df` before [sorting it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [reseting it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
samp_df.loc[-1] = samp_series
want = samp_df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

But this solution is more costly and will change your output if its index is not already sorted.